# UCWA - getting all meetings not just ones you scheduled

Tags: api, skype, lync, ucwa

I have managed to use the UCWA API for Skype for Business to pull back online meetings, however, this only seems to get information for meetings scheduled by the user themselves. Is there a way to view all scheduled meetings for the user?
This is the request I have been using:

```
GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/10XXXXXX052/onlineMeetings/myOnlineMeetings HTTP/1.1
Host: lywebext.contoso.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Authorization: Bearer cwt=AAEBHAEFAAAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

I have looked at other endpoints such as onlineMeetingInvitation but none of them seems to give meetings scheduled by other people with the user in question.

Thanks!